In EKF should Kalman Gain converge to a specific value?
I have implemented an EKF using the standard predict and update equations in order to perform state estimation of a vehicle with multiple sensors. The model has process covariance matrix $Q$ and each sensor $i$ has measurement covariance matrix $R_i$. However after a number of iterations Kalman Gain matrix $K$ converges to a specific value.
So my first question is whether this is correct and it should happen.
Secondly I try to tune the above covariance matrices and I change their values in order to notice the behaviour of my system. For example when I assign large covariances to process covariance matrix $Q$ the Kalman Gain should increase but it does not. Kalman Gain matrix $K$ remains the same independently of the large values pf $Q$. Is this something that should  happen or not?


... first question is whether this is correct (convergence of the Kalman gain matrix to a steady state) and it should happen.

Maybe, maybe not.
If you're modeling a linear, time-invariant system, then the Kalman gain matrix should reach steady state.
In an EKF, you're designing a system that pretends that a nonlinear system is a time-varying system, with the pseudo time variance actually being a dependence on the values of the system state.
I.e., you have a system that you can linearize for any given value of the state vector $\mathbf x$ and input vector $\mathbf u$, with Jacobians $\mathbf F (\mathbf x(n), \mathbf u(n))$ and $\mathbf H (\mathbf x(n), \mathbf u(n))$.  Then at each iteration of the filter you calculate these two matricies and pretend that your system is really defined by $\mathbf F(n)$ and $\mathbf H(n)$.
If you're using an EKF to model a nonlinear system, and the input $\mathbf u$ is constant, and the system is reaching some equilibrium, then your $\mathbf F(n)$ and $\mathbf H(n)$ will reach steady state, followed by the Kalman gain matrix also asymptotically reaching a steady value.
Similarly, but harder to conceptualize, there could be ranges of values of $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf u$ where $\mathbf F (\mathbf x(n), \mathbf u(n))$ and $\mathbf H (\mathbf x(n), \mathbf u(n))$ are constant over these ranges.  If your system is operating entirely within one of these ranges, then the Kalman filter will act like a linear Kalman filter and your Kalman gain will asymptotically approach a constant.
If you are definitely not meeting either of the above conditions, then in general your Kalman gain should be changing.

Kalman Gain matrix $\mathbf K$ remains the same independently of the large values of $\mathbf Q$. Is this something that should happen or not?

I think that if this is happening it's a good indication that something is wrong with your filter realization.  In general, your Kalman gain goes up as the eigenvalues of $\mathbf Q$ go up, or as the eigenvalues of $\mathbf R$ go down.  If you're adjusting the values of these covariances and the Kalman gain isn't responding then yes, something is probably wrong with your math or your code.
